# Camel exception handling behaviour when using interceptor

Tags: java, apache-camel

In a unit test I want to simulate that an `Exception` occurs.

I expect to receive one message at the "mock:count" endpoint, because of the `doTry/doCatch`-block. Why is this not happening and why is the `Exception` handled by the general `onException`-block?

```
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class TestClass extends CamelTestSupport {
   @Override
   protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
      return new RouteBuilder() {
         @Override
         public void configure() throws Exception {
            onException(Exception.class)
                  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "outer catch")
                  .handled(true);

            from("direct:start")
                  .doTry()
                     .to("mock:exception")

                  .doCatch(Exception.class)
                     .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "inner catch")
                     .to("mock:count")
                  .end();
         }
      };
   }

   @Test
   public void testBlaat() throws Exception {
      final SoapFault soapFault = new SoapFault("Something clearly went wrong", SoapFault.FAULT_CODE_CLIENT);
      Element detail = soapFault.getOrCreateDetail();
      Document doc = detail.getOwnerDocument();
      Text tn = doc.createTextNode("Fault details");
      detail.appendChild(tn);

      context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
         @Override
         public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:exception").throwException(new Exception("test"));
         }
      });

      template.sendBody("direct:start", "start");

      MockEndpoint endpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:count");
      endpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

      assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that exceptions thrown from an `AdviceWithRouteBuilder` are not seen by the `RouteDefinition`'s `doTry/doCatch` when the route is intercepted by the `AdviceWithRouteBuilder` because they are on different channels. The way to solve this is to use a mock for the endpoint and throw the exception from the mock:

```
getMockEndpoint("mock:exception").whenAnyExchangeReceived(new 
Processor() { 

            @Override 
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
                throw new Exception("fail me"); 
            } 
        });
```

See: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/question-about-exception-handling-behavior-td5743489.html

Also see this issue on JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6300
It is fixed in Camel 2.10.5 and other newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening to you, but I have an idea. I am thinking that your context is starting before reaching your test case and maybe your interceptor is being set up too late. Can you try the following?

Add this method:

```
@Override
public boolean isUseRouteBuilder() {
    return false;
}
```

Then use the regular way of defining the route with `context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){ .. })` instead of overriding `createRouteBuilder`. Also, define your interceptor here.

And after configuring your route and interceptor run `context.start()` in your test case. Try and let me know if it worked.

**UPDATE**:
Overriding `isUseRouteBuilder` is not required.

**UPDATE2:**

I have been running few tests and I am seeing the same behavior. It seems that onException always triggers before doCatch. Also, if you set `handled` to `true` the exception does not get propagated and does not reach the doCatch block.

Based on the documentation of [doTry doCatch doFinally](http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html) I would understand the error handler does not apply (*When using doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally then the regular Camel Error Handler does not apply*) but it seems the error handler and the onException are not the same.

Also, I have found this: [how to handle exception or fault in multiple routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731774/how-to-handle-exception-or-fault-in-multiple-routes) which could be helpful for you.

One last thing: you can define your interceptor in the same RouteBuilder:

```
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:exception").throwException(new Exception());

            onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("from onException");

                }

            }).handled(false);

            from("direct:start")
            //.errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
            .doTry()
                .to("mock:exception")
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .process(new Processor() {
                   @Override
                   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                       System.out.println("from doCatch");
                   }
                })
                .to("mock:count")
            .end();


        }
    });
```

Does this help?

Comment: This works, but only when I don't add the isUseRouteBuilder override.

Comment: I thought overriding that method was necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. When I comment out the .markRollBackOnly() and .handled(true) it works, but it seems that every exception passes that block first.

Comment: Thanks. In reality my route and interceptor are separated (production code / unit test).